# Site Search Settings and Query Parameter

Tags: google-analytics, search, site-search

I'm setting up [Google Analytics Site](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&utm_id=ad&answer=1012264) Search in my profile, and wondering if I need to add all the query parameters of the search (up to 5 of them) or just the parameter that contains the user's search; I can't really imagine what Google would do with the other search parameters, but they're Google so who knows what use they might have for them.

Comment: The documentation isn't real clear on this...https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&utm_id=ad&answer=1012264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the parameter that contains the user's search. When it says up to 5 parameters it means that if you have several search mechanisms and they use different parameters for the user's query then you can put all those in.